# Проверка ID в БД

Tags: php, база-данных, форма, выборка

Есть таблица в БД db_zadanie, в ней хранятся "id", "user", "iduser","text"

Хочу сделать так если в БД уже есть запись от пользователя, то задание ему не выдается, если нету то выдается, проверять решил по "iduser". Но нечего не выходит, всегда пользователь не найден.

```
   $id_zd_users = $_SESSION['user_id']; // ID пользователя
    $db->Query("SELECT * FROM `db_zadanie` WHERE `iduser`='$id_zd_users'") or die ('ошибка'.mysql_error);
    if(mysql_num_rows($db)>0) {
        echo 'Пользователь найден'; // тут что то будем делать
    } else {
        echo'пользователь не найден'; //тут что то будем делать
```

Comment: `echo  "SELECT * FROM \`db_zadanie\` WHERE \`iduser\`='$id_zd_users'";` Сразу за `$db->Query` выполните этот код, и результат в студию.

Comment: Выводит: SELECT * FROM `db_zadanie` WHERE `iduser`='2' и Пользователь не найден

Comment: а теперь вопрос, что хранится в БД у пользователей в поле `iduser`? точно не поле `id` надо проверять?

Comment: в iduser хранится порядковый номер, записывающийся при регистрации, он уникальный. Поле id это номер записи,  начиная с 1. Т.е по iduser должно проверяться.

Comment: *если в БД уже есть запись от пользователя, то задание ему не выдается, если нету то выдается* Создайте уникальный индекс по юзеру - и всего делов. Вторую запись для него в таблицу уже не вставить.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы решение нашлось

*Вместо:*

```
if(mysql_num_rows($db)>0) {}
```

*Нужно:*

```
if($db->NumRows() > 0){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется вместо этого можно использовать так

```
if(mysql`i`_num_rows($db)>0) {}
```

Comment: Какжется, что нет.